# UWP C# Как считать часть файла?

Tags: c#, файлы, uwp

Нужно считать, например, один символ или строку до разделителя. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Посмотрел на сайте microsoft [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files). Так и не разобрался как это сделать.

Это для реализации внешней сортировки.
Заранее спасибо :3

Comment: Избегайте задавать несколько вопросов в одном.

Comment: Хорошо, я буду знать в следующий раз

Comment: Символ не обязательно имеет длину в 1 байт.

Comment: @VladD тогда так "ReadString(sizeof(char))"?

Comment: Нет, конечно. Вы разве не слыхали о кодировках переменного размера?

Comment: @VladD теперь посмотрел, а не подскажете, как тогда поступить в моём случае?

Comment: @Алекс: Хм, я что-то не нахожу операцию, которая прочитает мне ровно один символ, или, скажем, ровно одну строку. Может, кто-то более опытный знает. Есть операции, которые читают блоки _байтов_, но это не то, что вам нужно, судя по всему.

Comment: @VladD всё равно спасибо за подсказку!)

Comment: UWP не имеет отношения к вопросу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот Вам простейший snippet, который читает файл из каталога, куда проинсталлировано приложение:

```
// Добавьте этот файл в проект
var path = @"MyTextFile.txt";
// Тут можно/нужно получить любой другой фолдер, но это будет уже другой вопрос
var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
// читаем файл
var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("MyTextFile.txt");
var lines = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    // Строки будут выводиться в окне Output Visual Studio
    // с ними можно делать все, что угодно
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но всё же, разве здесь считываются строки по очереди? Метод "ReadLinesAsyn" "возвращает содержимое файла в виде списка (тип IVector) строк текста. Каждая строка текста в этом списке представлена объектом String.".

Comment: @SеNS  Мне же нужно чтобы в память считывалась строка, потом удалялась из памяти и считывалась другая.. Все не влезут сразу

Comment: ```Все не влезут сразу```


Могу Вас уверить (и Вы вполне можете мне доверять), что на UWP устройстве (даже из доступных IOT, не говоря уже про десктопы, таблетки и телефоны) - влезут запросто, даже многомегабайтные! 

Если же Вы имеете ввиду многогигабайтные строки террабайтных текстовых файлов, то Вы серьезно ошиблись с архитектурой и имплементацией.

P.S. Отдельного метода для построчного считывания в API Windows Runtime не существует за его полной ненадобностью (в современных условиях), но его можно реализовать. Впрочем, сложность  правильной реализации выходит за рамки вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если правильно понял вопрос то можно так сделать

```
 var str = File.ReadAllText("file.txt");
    var newstr = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("!"));
```

str.IndexOf("!") символ до какова читаем или можно число задать

Comment: Этих функций нет в WinRT. Но если бы и были, вопрос в том, как прочитать _часть_.

Comment: ну подстрока по сути часть строки и читает

Comment: Но вопрос-то, как прочитать из файла! Допустим, файл такой большой, что не помещается в память (для чего ещё нужна внешняя сортировка?)

Comment: Ну можно попробывать в потоке считывать

Comment: @Санитариум, в том то и проблема, что не получается это сделать :)